# Разные результаты одинаковых функций

Tags: c++

Почему следующая программа выводит `1 0`, хотя вроде бы одинаковые проверки?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_copy_assignable<int>() << std::endl << std::is_assignable<int, int>();
}
```

Comment: "вроде бы одинаковые" != "одинаковые"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::is_assignable<int, int>` проверяет(без выполнения), будет ли корректным выражение

```
::std::declval<int>() = ::std::declval<int>()
int x{}; int y{}; ::std::move(y) = ::std::move(x); // не работает
```

Это выражение некорректно, так как слева должно быть `l-value`

А `std::is_copy_assignable<int>()` выдает результат аналогичный

```
::std::is_assignable<int &, int const &>
::std::declval<int &>() = ::std::declval<int const &>()
int const x{}; int y{}; y = x; // работает
```